# Azure Streaming URL validity

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I'm currently looking into Azure Streaming service for client purposes and I am wondering if there is a way to create time limited URL for Adaptive Streaming (we need this for security purposes, when user wants to stream, we verify permissions then create time limited URL). I see that Streaming Locator can have the end date, but is it really the best practice to create new Streaming Locator each time when someone requests the stream? That means I would need to persist them, then clean them up after expiration. Is there any better way to create time limited URL for adaptive streaming in Azure Media Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend looking at the token authentication capabilities available in Azure CDN from Verizon Premium SKU - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth. This would be the simplest path to take. The Azure CDN from Verizon Premium SKU can be enabled directly from configuration on your streaming endpoint. The endpoint will need to be stopped in order to enable Azure CDN for it. You could also accomplish directly using content protection capabilities available in Media Services - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-content-protection-overview. This path is much more complex one to take and would require significantly more development work.